# I can't get the for loop to get the average of the integers, it keeps giving me 0s, but I need the average of the numbers after the first number

Tags: java

The code is supposed to get the average of the numbers after the first number, so for the first line [3 1 2 3] average is 2.0 because (1 +2 +3=6/3 = 2.0), but the code is just giving me 0s.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
   
   File num = new File("numbers.txt");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(num));
   String st;
    
   int first, number ;
    
   while((st = br.readLine())!= null){
       int j= st.length()-1;
       int average =0;
       int i;
       first = Integer.parseInt(st.substring(0, st.indexOf(" ")));
       int sum = 0; // initialize sum
       for( i = j;i< j; i++ ){
          String str = st; //each line from the file
          String [] segments = str.split(" ");
          int [] values = Stream.of(segments)
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                    .toArray();
         
          for (int c = 0; c < values.length; c++){
             sum+=values[c];
          }
          sum = sum/first;
       }
       
       System.out.println("The average of the " + first + " integers"+ " " 
                  + st.substring(2) + " the average is "+ sum);
       
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your outer for-loop you initialize `i` with `j` and then go on to check, whether or not `i < j`. This condition will never be true and therefore your for-loop will never run a single time.

Although to me it doesn't look like you need the outer loop at all, since you never use `i` nor does the code make sense, if executed multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you're making this very difficult.  I recommend the following:

- Use a scanner to read the values.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(..));
```

Then you can use `scanner.nextInt()` to read in the value as an int.  If you need to see if more ints are available you can check `scanner.hasNextInt()`

- There is no need to use an array as you can sum the values as you read them
- The first value is the count so you can get the average (and use that as the loop count).
- just make certain you sum the values in a `double` and not an int. Otherwise you will loose fractions.  eg. `10/4 == 2` but `10./4 == 2.5`

Check out [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) for more information.